# LibGDX internal calls to MathUtils.random() interfere with the sequence of random numbers generated

Tags: random, libgdx, box2d

While using a random number generator (RNG) with a given seed several times (ie. each time calling `setSeed()` with the same seed to start over), I have encountered some deviation in the sequence of numbers generated on each pass. After banging my head against the wall a few times I found the reason to be this:

`box2d`'s `World.createBody()` calls `LongMap.put()`, which calls `LongMap.push()`, which calls `MathUtils.random()` inside a `while` loop.

To my knowledge particle effects call `MathUtils.random()` too.

So how can I trust a sequence of numbers to always repeat itself if LibGDX internally uses the same static RNG instance and therefor could mess up the sequence?

How am I supposed to know exactly where and when `MathUtils.random()` gets called outside my code?

Comment: maybe report it as bug?

Comment: There could be a reason behind it and/or a way to work around it that I'm not aware of. I'm just asking a question, albeit with some frustration :)

Comment: Could you not create your own Random class for your code and not use libgdx's MathUtils.random one? libgdx does call its own random() in several spots. If you want your own code to have a known seeded sequence, use your own random object in your code and keep libgdx's random to its own internal workings?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm doing now. I basically just copied the RNG part of MathUtils into my own class. The question, though, is why providing a shared RNG instance in the first place. It defies the whole point of using a seed. You'd expect there to be a comment of warning at least because otherwise, when an instance is provided to you, why would you ever think you had to create your own. Again, that is unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Peter R It occurs to me that I should probably post this question directly to badlogic/libgdx. For the benefit of anyone who might hit a similar wall and come across this page, the custom RNG may well be the pain relief, and you did post it. Please post it as an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: Well libgdx's MathUtils simply uses Random from the java library, and many other libgdx classes use this RNG. Creating multiple RNGs in an application is not too taxing, so libgdx uses its own, moreso I would guess internally even though the member is public. But if you need custom seeded RNG capabilities in your own app, create your own (which it sounds like you have) and let libgdx use the one it has. Probably written this way specifically for situations like yours - where you want control in one aspect of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Peter R, one can create one's own RNG which guarantees nothing would interfere with the sequence of numbers.

Either Java's Random can be used:

```
import java.util.Random;

private Random random = new Random();
```

or RandomXS128 that is used by MathUtils (which extends Java's Random but is faster):

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.RandomXS128;

private Random random = new RandomXS128();
```

The convenient wrapper methods (random() signatures) in MathUtils can be used too (copied into one's own class) as per needed, whether static or not. eg:

```
/** Returns a random number between start (inclusive) and end (inclusive). */
public int random (int start, int end) {
    return start + random.nextInt(end - start + 1);
}

/** Returns a random number between start (inclusive) and end (exclusive). */
public float random (float start, float end) {
    return start + random.nextFloat() * (end - start);
}
```

For myself I'm still befuddled as to why MathUtils provides a shared RNG to be used both internally and externally, which makes using it with a seed unsafe, and with no mention of that in the comments.

But the above workaround should be satisfactory to anyone who is not as petty as I am.